# String Manipulation in PHP: split on first space

Tags: php, string, php-5.3

In my PHP 5.3 application I get string

eg: `ACTION data with lot of spaces`

I need to get ACTION and 'data with lot of space' as two strings.

I have few actions.

Comment: Show us what you have tried

Comment: `list($action, $restOfString) = explode(' ', $originalString, 2);` - pretty basic stuff

Comment: I tried with explode with spaces.But since it contains many spaces It didn't worked @Epodax

Comment: If you tried and failed, then you didn't bother reading about the `limit` argument in the [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Comment: Maybe if you were more specific about the string you are trying to break up we could stop guessing and be more specific in return

Comment: @MarkBaker thanks. I'm trying it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `explode()` like this,

```
print_R(explode(' ', 'ACTION data with lot of spaces', 2));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ACTION
    [1] => data with lot of spaces
)
```

See demo [here](https://eval.in/467533)

Comment: Bro. Today you are in full form. Attempting each question. Ha Ha :D leave some for me too. ;)

Comment: @NanaPartykar i started just now. my second answer for the day.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly you can use one of the below approaches:

1. split by spaces: `list($action, $data) = explode(' ', $action_string, 2);`
2. split by regular expression: `preg_match('/(\w+)\s(.*)/', $action_string, $matches);` (`$matches[1]` will be action, `$matches[2]` will be rest data)
3. split and re-combine: `$parts = explode(' ',$action_string); $action = array_shift($parts); $data = implode(' ', $parts);`